# How best to create edges based on a property common to 2 vertices?

Tags: database, orientdb, graph-databases, orientdb2.2

I have 2 vertex classes - EMPLOYEE and BRANCH which are both populated with data and I want an edge class InBranch to be their relationship.

So Employee -InBranch-> Branch.

Class Employee with properties -> empname, branchname.
Class Branch with propety --> branchname.

**Instead of a common property** (branchname) **as relationship**, 
I would like to **make these as edges** (InBranch).

I'm trying to make work a construct similar to below:

```
CREATE EDGE InBranch FROM (SELECT FROM Employee) TO (SELECT FROM Branch) WHERE Employee.branchname = Branch.branchname
```

which is intuitively patterned after Luca Garulli's code :

```
create edge Owns from (select from Person) to (select from Country)
```

from [OrientDB: Using Schemas with Graphs, Part 1](http://orientdb.com/orientdb-using-schemas-with-graphs-part-1/).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you can't do it directly via sql, but you can use a JS function:

```
var g = orient.getGraph();
var emp = g.command('sql','select from Employee');

for each (a in emp){
  br = g.command('sql','select from Branch where branchname = "' + a.getProperty('branchname') + '"');
  for each (b in br){
    g.command('sql','create edge inBranch from ' + a.getId() + ' to ' + b.getId());
   }
}
```

Comment: Thanks for this. I wish this could also be done in the future using sql via where clause.